# Managing Similar but Different Configuration Scripts Across Multiple Different Instalations

Tags: configuration, version-control, config

We have a physical machine with multiple configuration parameters which are managed in a `NSUserDefaults plist`. These parameters can be bulk updated with a simple shell script `machineX.defaults.sh`.

### Issue

As multiple engineers work on their respective machines they add configuration keys to the shell parameters list, however each machine has a slightly different configuration. Many values will be the same, some will be different, with a unique config for each machine.

What is a good way to manage all default parameter lists having the same "keys" and basic layout, but having bespoke values depending on the machine?

### Example

Machine 1:

```
param1 -> value1
param2 -> value2
```

Machine 2:

```
param1 -> value1
param2 -> value4
```

Developer on Machine 1 adds `param3` with default `value5` to his config file. I would like all config files to have `param3` available on the config file with the default value.

### Possible Solutions and Associated issues

1. Have a `master` config file which individual developers can Push and Pull to from their own `local` machine configs.
   This is a bit messy and requires constant careful management to avoid overwriting parameters.
2. Build a central database with config parameters for each machine which holds the config data for each machine and exports it in the correct format based on the machine. New parameters could be added by any developer to this database.

Is there a better way to do this? I feel this is already a problem which has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Configuration management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management) is separate, special and *slightly different* from plain "configuration"|"vesion-control"|"config" businesses: CM **is not** SCM or VCS
2. As part of modern fashion named "DevOps", CM have own set of "bells and whistles", lingua and subcultures (Chef-boys, Ansible-boys etc etc) and permanent wars between them
3. Due to pp 1-2, you have to:

- Select *your own* tools from set of ["Best 5 CM tools"](https://opensource.com/article/18/12/configuration-management-tools) f.e. (old, but rather good and brain-powered artile) or from wider set
- Grok it
- Ask more detailed questions, targeted to most relevant to your choice and tools target audience, here: any CM-tool is usable for your (standard for CM) tasks and choice is always a questions of just habits, mileage, time and money